# Compiling old C code Y2038 conform still results in 4 byte variables

Tags: c, linux, glibc, libc

According to [this overview](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Y2038ProofnessDesign) in order to compile Y2038 conform old code, we just need to add the preprocessor macro `__USE_TIME_BITS64` to `gcc`, but that does not seem to work on an ARMv7 board with Debian 12 (bookworm):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct stat sb;

    printf("sizeof time_t: %zu\n", sizeof(time_t));
    printf("sizeof stat timestamp: %zu\n", sizeof(sb.st_atime));

    return 0;
}
```

time_t is still 4 bytes:

```
root@debian:~# gcc -D__USE_TIME_BITS64 time.c -o time
root@debian:~# ./time
sizeof time_t: 4
sizeof stat timestamp: 4
root@debian:~#
```

glibc is 2.33, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://lwn.net/Articles/664800/) (which is getting a little old now, and some parts of which are probably no longer relevant):

> ... defining `_TIME_BITS=64` would cause all time functions to use 64-bit times by default. The `_TIME_BITS=64` option is implemented by transparently mapping the standard functions and types to their internal 64-bit variants. Glibc would also set `__USE_TIME_BITS64`, which user code can test for to determine if the 64-bit variants are available.

Presumably, this includes making `time_t` 64 bit.

So if your version of glibc supports this at all, it looks like you're setting the wrong macro.  You want:

`-D_TIME_BITS=64`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, `gcc -D_TIME_BITS=64 time.c -o time` results in 4 byte also, unfortunately.

Comment: Bummer.  [It looks like you need glibc 2.34](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-gnulib@gnu.org/msg41063.html).  In addition, according to that link, you also need `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.  It's all a bit messy, isn't it?

Comment: You are right, with glibc 2.34 and `gcc -D_TIME_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 time.c -o time` it works. Thanks!